# nested array with json

Tags: php, arrays, nested

```
$url2 = "http://www.website.com/test.json";
$json2 = file_get_contents($url2);
$data2 = json_decode($json2);

foreach($data2 as $mydata2) {

    $product_discount = $mydata2->applied_discounts;
    var_dump($product_discount);
}
```

This is returning:

```
array(1) {
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
        ["id"]=> string(6) "coupon"
        ["amount"]=> float(9.99)
    }
}
```

I want to return just the amount of "9.99"

I tried $product_discount[0]['amount'], but that doesn't seem to be right??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an object, so you need the following syntax:

```
$product_discount = $mydata2->applied_discounts[0]->amount;
```

However, if you want an array instead, you could set [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode)'s second parameter as `TRUE`:

```
$data2 = json_decode($json2, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to do this:

```
$product_discount = $mydata2->applied_discounts[0]->amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an object, not an array. Try...

```
$product_discount[0]->amount
```